# RecyclerView inside Dialog is truncated bottom

Tags: java, android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-dialog

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/popupCategoriesLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popu_category_info"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPopupCategoryInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/popu_category_info"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/popu_category_info"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_outline_orange_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popu_category_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/popup_warning_category"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/warning_category_info"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So I want info label at the top of my dialog + scrollable list. Code to show dialog:

```
CategoryGroupAdapter gropupAdapter = new CategoryGroupAdapter(categoryGroups);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_category, null);

        RecyclerView list = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_categories);
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        list.setHasFixedSize(false);

        list.setAdapter(gropupAdapter);

        gropupAdapter.collapseAll();

        AlertDialog d = alertDialog.setView(convertView).setCancelable(true).setTitle(getString(R.string.category_dialog_title)).show();
```

As the result, I am getting my list truncated at the bottom if entire list has no room to display all items. It seems it's truncated of the info label height (but I can't set fixed info label height, because it needs to show all text on all devices with various dpi).

Any ideas how to display my dialog correctly?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Batter you post the screenshot of your implementation to improve your question.

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: What's the root `ViewGroup` of the dialog layout file?

Comment: I corrected my post, as I understand what are you asking, it's `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score -1):

Create an custom dialog extending Dialog fragment and passed required data through constructor and set them on dialog UI as per your need.

```
    public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    Context context;

    public AlertDialogFragment(){
    }

    //Create a multiple constructor on your need
    onStart(){
        //Set your logic if any like button color or UI on flag
    }

     @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.customalertstyle)
                // set dialog icon
                // set Dialog Title
                .setTitle(title)
                // Set Dialog Message
                .setItems(items, itemClickListner)
                .setMessage(msg)
                // positive button
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, positiveClickListner)
                .setOnKeyListener(keyListener)
                .setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText, negativeClickListner);

    }


     @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        //to catch the exception while app is in background and dialog
        try {
            super.show(manager, tag);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        super.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**Don't forgot to use support dialog fragment as another one is deprecated.**

Comment: What is `setItems`? I need my custom layout and custom recycler view. Where will you set dialog layout in your case?

Comment: @user1209216 The setItem method is consist of two parameters as item and click listener where items are some values that you can pass in as array and click listener are event which you can pass, else just don't use them if needed

Comment: Well, but as far as I understand, your approach changes nothing. You have only packed some boilerplate stuff into custom class. My problem is dialog layout, which is scaled some way I don't understand. This not the first time when Android dialog makes me confusing

Comment: @user1209216 Then try to auto size you text as per your need

Comment: I am out of ideas how to scale it. The same layout works fine if placed in Activity. Do you have any suggestion? From what I know, everything is scaled correctly in my code.

Comment: @user1209216 It pretty difficult to say as its maps pixel by pixel in android